# Javascript call Public function on Activex

Tags: javascript, vb6, activex

I´m trying to call a function from javascript to ActiveX. It worked but now, i have to update the activeX because of Internet Explorer 8 and Windows 7.

But for now, i can´t call the function. When i try, i got a message: Object is not a collection.

What i suppose to do?

Here´s the piece of code:

```
Public Function Text(strTxt As String) As String
    If result Then
        Text = "Authenticated"
    Else
        Text = "Not authenticated"
    End If
End Function
```

In Javascript:

```
function leDado()
    {
        try { 
            var x=document.getElementById("MyActivex")
            document.MainForm.resultado.value = x.Text("Test string")
            x = 0;
        } 
        catch(e) { 
            alert(e.message); 
        }
    }
```

In the form, when i press the button, i call that function. 
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

So you’ve updated the ActiveX object; did that break binary compatibility? If so, did you unregister and re-register the library before testing it?  Can you debug the object 'live'?

Comment: Hi man! Thanks for your reply. 

Yestarday night this script begin to work. As you said, i guess the VB was not compiling the ocx. I discover it putting a new label on the usercontrol. 
I try to compile but, vb said that i haven't rights, so i close VB and delete ocx. 
After that i compile the ocx and my scripts begin to work. 

Thanks ! ;)